# Webview in chrome packaged app cannot be full screen

Tags: javascript, webview, google-chrome-app

I have two pages, one is "index.html". It is used by a chrome packaged app and it has a webview inside. The other one is a fullscreen.html and it has a button with function:
`document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen()`.

So I point webview to fullscreen.html. But when I wanted to click button to full screen both webview and app, nothing happened.

Comment: you need this http://stackoverflow.com/a/31842092/146032

Answer (score 0):

It sounds from your description that the request for full screen is being executed in the webview's DOM, not the top window's DOM. If so, what you describe sounds normal to me. What is in effect a child window can't be fullscreen.

Comment: So If want this feature, maybe I need send message between two windows?

Comment: That might work. Or, if the JavaScript running in the webview's context can get the window object of the top-level window, it can call a JavaScript function in the context of the main window directly, or even access the main window's document object and reference its methods and properties.